# Issue adding data from csv to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a PHP code that is supposed to save values fro a CSV file into a MySql database table. Everything works fine except that only the first row of the CSV is added. Here's the code:

```
<?php

 public function saveProductsFromCsv($productId, $val) {

      $productId = (int) $productId;

      $data = array();

      $fieldNames = $this->_config->getCsvColumnNames();

      array_shift($fieldNames); 

      $numberOfFields = count($fieldNames);

      $lines = explode("\n", $val);
      foreach ($lines as $line) {
      $line = trim($line);

        if (empty($line))
          continue;

        $values = explode(',', $line);

        if (count($values) != $numberOfFields){
          throw new Exception();          
          return;          
        }

        $make = trim($values[0]);
        $model = trim($values[1]);
        $yearFrom = (int) $values[2];
        $yearTo = (int) $values[3];
        $engine = trim($values[4]);

        if ($yearFrom > 0){
          if ($yearFrom < 1950){
            $yearFrom = 1950;
          } elseif ($yearFrom > 2030){
            $yearFrom = 2030;
          }                        
        }

        if ($yearTo > 0){
          if ($yearTo < 1950){
            $yearTo = 1950;
          } elseif ($yearTo > 2030){
            $yearTo = 2030;
          }                        
        }        

        $data[] = array($productId, $make, $model, $yearFrom, $yearTo, $engine);        
      }

      if (count($data) > 0){
        $this->saveValues($data);
      }                   
    } 

    public function saveValues($data)
    {         
      $valuesStr = '';    
      foreach ($data as $values){
        $cell = '';
        foreach ($values as $value)
          $cell .= ",'" . esc_sql(trim($value)). "'";

        $valuesStr .= ($valuesStr != '' ? ',' : '') . "(NULL{$cell})";     
      }

      $this->_wpdb->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO {$this->_mainTable} VALUES {$valuesStr}");                  
    } 

    ?>
```

Below is the CSV:

```
product_sku,make,model,year_from,year_to,engine
63118,Toyota,FJ Cruiser,2000,2008,V6 4.7L 2UZ-FE 20R/22R 1st Gen FJ Cruiser
28216,Toyota,GX470,1992,1997,V8 4.7L 2UZ-FE GX470
62687,Toyota,Land Cruiser,1998,2007,V8 4.7L 2UZ-FE 100-Series
28485,Toyota,Land Cruiser,2007,2018,V8 5.7L 3UR-FE 200-Series
```

Incidentally, if I use this:

```
product_sku,make,model,year_from,year_to,engine
63118,Toyota,FJ Cruiser,2000,2008,engine1
28216,Toyota,GX470,1992,1997,engine2
62687,Toyota,Land Cruiser,1998,2007,engine3
28485,Toyota,Land Cruiser,2007,2018,engine4
```

everything gets inserted fine. I think the problem is with the last column because if I use the same values in the last column in the second or third columns, everything works fine.

Comment: Why don't you use fgetcsv()?

Comment: I don't need fgetcsv() when this works. There's just something that I'm not doing right that makes it insert just the first row but if I change the last column, all rows get inserted fine.

Comment: Well, obviously it does not work, or why are you posting on SO?
Have you started debugging your code? I don't see you querying for database errors at all.

Comment: Why don't you use MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I've solved it. The problem was with the encoding of the CSV file. I changed it to UTF-8 and everything is working fine.